# simple paranoid question about sudo and passwd

Tags: sudo, passwd

using Linux at my home place, i wonder what if the end-user, say having just installed/deployed say Ubuntu, typed just (being messy while searching for the command, and thinking **it's shorter so it's better**) `sudo passwd` instead of a more complete `sudo passwd $USERNAME`. What happens concretely in each case, and would the end-user's password be effectively changed as intended ? Thanks.

Comment: yes effectivelly :( quote "Of course, as always running a program with sudo (without additional arguments) makes it behave as if it were run by root" :crybabycry:

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/passwd.1.html):

> The `passwd` command changes passwords for user accounts. A normal user may only change the password for their own account, while the superuser may change the password for any account.  `passwd` also changes the account or associated password validity period.

Not supplying a username will set the current account’s password. Non-sudo accounts can only change their own.

Comment: Non-sudo accounts ? What does it mean ?

Comment: While this answer may be *technically* correct, it misses the important point that "the current account" in the case of `sudo passwd` is `root` (since `getuid` will return `0` when run under sudo).